# Qt: Morph-ing QPushButton into QCommandLinkButton makes related icon to be partially displayed

Tags: qt, icons, qpushbutton

I am using Qt5 on Windows 7.
In my current app I had a QPushButton with an icon on it, some sort of speaker icon, like presented below:
[image]

So far so good, but I wanted the above push-button to be morph-ed into a QCommandLinkButton, as it has a very nice feature (I think Windows Vista has something similar): normally it is displayed like a label, without a border, but when you put/hover the mouse over it, it shows the border/edges just like a regular push-button.
After morph-ing (I just used the Qt Creator feature "Morph into..."), compiling/building and running, I got this nasty surprise:
[image]

Well, even if it shows the border only when hovering the mouse over it (that's what I wanted in the first place), the problem is that the related icon is *lowered* somehow (I don't know why) and as a consequence only part of it is displayed...
Worth mention that the size of the new control (QCommandLinkButton) is **identical** to the original QPushButton (I can see that when I put the mouse over it), so I see no reason why it behaves like that. I tried to pull-up the icon using Qt Creator, but with no success...

So, **the question** : Is it possible to fix this somehow without altering the other controls/widgets below? i.e.: I wouldn't want to increase the vertical space that was previously reserved for the push-button.
Thanks in advance for your time and patience :)

Comment: The `QCommandLinkButton` has a different size than a `QPushButton`. What exactly do you mean by "fixing" it? Have you tried styling the button to make it smaller?

Comment: "Fixing it" = make it work properly. I tried to make it smaller: it gets smaller, but unfortunately the icon shows up incomplete (it is not displayed in its full content, but rather truncated), hard to explain... same as in the image above - see the red circle - an image says more than thousand words :)

Comment: I guess I was expecting too much from this morphing... An "acceptable" alternative would be to set the _flat_ property = true for the QPushButton. Not as good, but... I must go on/move forward somehow!

Comment: QCommandLinkButton has a large minimum size to match the style of the command link button in Windows Vista. Note that it is not intended to be an icon-only, but rather primarily text-driven, control. Command links buttons are usually used in layouts with lots of room.

Comment: You are correct in using the `flat` property for a `QPushButton` instead.

Comment: Some trick would be to _activate_ the push-button border when mouse over it and _make it flat again_ when mouse leaves the push-button area. But I guess this is too complicate... not sure if it worth the effort[?].